# Completely Unable to Define the UpdateCallback of System.Runtime.Caching

Tags: c#, .net, caching

I'm having a difficult time using the *CacheEntryUpdateCallback* delegate of the *System.Runtime.Caching* library. Whenever I define and set the callback, I get an ArgumentException that the "CacheItemUpdateCallback must be null". Why must it be null? I should be able to set this and then get the callback.

I do not get this when using the *CacheEntryRemovedCallback* delegate. I can reliably reproduce this in all of my projects. Am I doing something wrong? Here's a small sample application:

```
using System.Runtime.Caching;
class Program {
  static void Main(string[] args) {
    var policy = new CacheItemPolicy();
    policy.SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

    // this works
    //policy.RemovedCallback = Removed;

    // this creates the exception
    policy.UpdateCallback = Update;

    MemoryCache.Default.Add("test", "123", policy);
    Console.Read();
  }

  static void Update(CacheEntryUpdateArguments arguments) { }
  static void Removed(CacheEntryRemovedArugments arguments) { }
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

According to documentation you should be using `Set` instead of `Add`.

[MemoryCache.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh138343%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The `Add` and `AddOrGetExisting` method overloads do not support the UpdateCallback property. Therefore, to set the UpdateCallback property for a cache entry, use the `Set` method overloads instead.

Following indeed work without problems:

```
MemoryCache.Default.Set("test", "123", policy);
```